# React basic form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am new to React and learning it on my own, I am trying to implement a simple form where the user can provide a name and it will then be store is the state. Once he stop typing and clink on send the the name is store and the fields is
in the input is reset not the state.
This is what i tried and i get

> an error saying that cannot read property "then"

```
    changeFun = (e) => {
       this.setState({name: e.target.value})
    }

    submitFun = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      this.setState({ name: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <input type = "text" value={this.state.name}/>
        <button 
           onSubmit = {(e) => 
             this.submitFun(e).then(
               () => reset()           
             ) 
           onchange ={this.changeFun}}>
           SEND
        </button>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Please give the code as you have it in the editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what are you trying to achieve is called **Controlled Component!** more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

the base of Controlled Component is basically you have a property in your state and a form element (i.e and input element). then you chain that input value to your state by a function, and that function is going to run on `onChange` event, to update the state on every change.

something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const _tempValue = e.target.value

    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({inputValue: _tempValue})
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    const {inputValue} = this.state

    e.preventDefault()
    // here is your data
    // save it to redux or do what ever you want to
    console.log(inputValue)

    // last thing here is gonna be to reset state after submition
    this.setState({inputValue: ""})
  }

  render() {
    const {inputValue} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="type something"
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <p>{inputValue}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is a basic implementation of what you want to do, its here: https://codesandbox.io/s/m39w10olnp

on the example that you provide though , you using `then` that is basically used when that you returning a promise from a function, something like this:

```
export const giveMeArray= () => {
  return new Promise( (res,rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(Object.assign([], myArray))
    }, delay);
  })
}
```

so as you can see there is no need to use `then` here, check my simple example to implement in a better way!

Comment: I like you answer, the only thing that i wonder after i click send the state goes back to the default values --- after send <p> {this.state.name}</p> it show the default value once i click <input type"submit"/>

Comment: for that you need to have a seperate function like `handleSubmit` to take care of resetting state after submission, i updated the example in here and code sandbox for you

Answer (score 1):

`submitFun` is not returning a promise. So you can't use `.then` after it.

```
 submitFun = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   // this.setState({name: e.target.value}) should not be here
   // because e.target is <button/> 
   this.setState({name: ''}) // This will reset the input value
 }
 <button onClick = {this.submitFun} onchange ={this.changeFun}>SEND</button>
```

In addition you need to use `onClick` instead of `onSubmit` for `<button>` tag.
`onSubmit` will be used for `<form>` tag.

Comment: this.reset is not a function ----- and I want to reset the input not the state

Comment: this.setState({name: ''}) will reset the input value because the input value is synced with the state.